# Azure - can't remove SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Something went wrong, I can't connect to Azure SQL server. I try to remove it
[image]

[image]
but get an error:

> Failed to delete the server: ***.  ErrorCode: 504  ErrorMessage:
>   {"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not
>   receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql' within the specified

Nothing more info. Just I see in notifications, that infinite restoring process of database, included in this SQL Server.

How can I remove SQL server forcibly?

**ADDED:**

Deleting is being during 10 hours

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, by removing SQL Server? How are you trying to remove it? And: Did you set up SQL Server in a VM? Are you using the SQL Database *service*? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I try to remove it click on "Delete", I even can't imagine how to delete it another way. I don't have SQL server in a VM, just this one http://www.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/MmixFOB2W0k.html

Comment: Please - don't embed some link to an image, especially in a comment. Edit your question and properly embed the image. I have no idea what you're clicking on, either. What 'Delete' button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please wait for the restore process to complete and then delete the Azure SQL Server . If the restore process doesn’t complete after a period of time, I would recommend you directly open a support ticket in Azure portal.